# ImageMagick < 6.9.3-9 - Multiple Vulnerabilities question

Tags: exploit, metasploit

Do you know any contain management system or other applications that are affected by the [recent](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39767/) ImageMagick exploits? (I have already played with convert tool which is offered on Linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get a solid answer for this. But not many are at risk even if they are running at risk versions of ImageMagick.

First one would have to be able to figure out how many PHP applications are live with ImageMagick installed and configured. No major CMS or PHP application requires the ImageMagick library. For image manipulation the GD2 library is the standard go to and the GD lib has been included since PHP 4.2. So if someone is using ImageMagick they would have to install and configure it to work with PHP themself. With applications like Wordpress they would then have to install and enable a plugin to use ImageMagick as well. Typically shared hosts do not install Image Magick with PHP installs either due to it's history of exploits.

Further more the install and usage of ImageMagick is not enough to make it exploitable. For example, most of the image manipulation is done on the back end of a CMS. (Uploading an image and getting different sizes the CMS can use for example.) And if the public front end is doing real time processing they would have to be able to exploit the front end code to attack ImageMagick. So at this point you are looking for 2 exploits. One to exploit the web application that interacts with ImageMagicks PHP APIs and then an exploit in ImageMagick that is possible through ImageMagicks PHP APIs.

The exploit you mentioned in your question is possible through a PHP application if all the moons are aligned. Especially if the filename input is controlled by the front facing user. But basic input sanitation or the PHP application having control over the filename should be enough to stop this attack. The proof of concept (shell.php) does not implement these but the idea of the proof of concept is to see if it is exploitable, not defendable.

So to sum this up: **Not many PHP applications or content management systems are likely to be affected.**

Comment: `Not many...` - but some. I have a few servers with users that specifically needed `ImageMagick`, just for those users, how would I protect them?!

Comment: @blade19899 Like I mentioned they might have it, even at risk versions but might not be vulnerable at all. So when I say not many are at risk I really mean it. This includes the possibility your client's are not at risk either. The very few that are affected should for starters patch their PHP application. Because if the exploits can be performed through the website they don't sound like they are well maintained code bases in the first place. As far as general protection you can find migration procedures at: https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39767/

Comment: Already did the fixes in that link, for the previous exploit!